# MVC reCaptcha Validation fails

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, recaptcha

First of all i am new to mvc and c# and i might have made simple error but so far i have not found solution for it. Here is the problem. I have created a contact form and i want to add recaptcha to it. 
I generated google's recaptcha key-s:
[google keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3D2v.png)
i have added recaptcha tags to my wanted view where it was specified by google

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY PUBLIC KEY"></div>
@Html.ValidationMessage("CapchaError", new { @style = "color:red" });

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

here is how i check for validation in my controller

```
//reCaptcha
        var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
        string secretKey = "MY SECRET KEY";
        var client = new WebClient();
        var result = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secretKey, response));
        var obj = JObject.Parse(result);
        var status = (bool)obj.SelectToken("success");

        if (!status)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CapchaError", "***");
        }
```

the problem is that validation works perfectly fine in localhost but i can't get it working on my domain(web-site). it prints my "CaptchaError", ***
i tried to generate new keys for only domain(didn't work), for both domain and localhost(worked for localhost only).
i am sure i made stupid error but i can't figure out what have i done wrong so please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: When returning `false` they also include error codes, according to the docs there are several possible reasons. You just have to add error code inspection to your snippet. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: Have you added the new domain into the google captcha account for the key, because it should work otherwise. Under key setting/domain add new domain

Comment: Saurabh Chauhan yes i have specified domain and tried but unfortunetly didn't work...